# 'No such file or directory' error in sh, but the file exists?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm running a command to retrieve the location of a logfile using from a `.sh bash script`

```
rig=`forever list | grep 'server.*root.*\.log' | awk '{print $8}'`
```

echoing it prints:

```
echo $rig
/root/.forever/1cFY.log
```

But when I try to read the file (which exists) like so:

```
less $rig
```

I get:

```
/root/.forever/1cFY.log: No such file or directory
```

However if I manually enter the file name without my `.sh script` it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: `strace -f less $rig` could helps you to find what's happens

Comment: Yea Im running it as sudo su

Comment: The output is: `execve("/usr/bin/less", ["less", "\33[35m/root/.forever/1cFY.log\33[39"...], [/* 21 vars */]) = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have grep configured to output color.  Just drop the grep and use awk:

```
rig=$(forever list | awk '/server.*root.*\.log/{print $8}')
```

Comment: seems that awk is also outputing color, getting same error

Comment: More likely the escape sequences are coming from `forever`.

Comment: This did it -> `rig=$(forever list | awk '/server.*root.*\.log/{print $8}' | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g")`

Comment: @user3490755: Can't you configure `forever` (I don't know what that is) so it doesn't print those escape sequences in the first place?

Comment: By default, `grep` with `--color` will output colour only when its stdout is a attached to a TTY (auto mode)